# How to find reason for unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have search bar, if user enters something, then the data comes from server to the view, while entering the data for multiple times (searching and canceling and again searching) application is crashing showing "Unhandled exception".

I placed try-catch everywhere and placed breakpoints but none of them were hit.

Here is my log:

```
11-01 11:37:12.010 D/Mono    ( 3385): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
11-01 11:37:12.010 D/Mono    ( 3385): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
An unhandled exception occured.

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #32
11-01 11:37:21.454 D/Mono    ( 3385): [0xb9965e80] worker finishing
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of situation i goto the logs of xamarin
**Visual Studio -> Help -> Xamarin -> Open Logs** 
Open Selected file which will show you logs related to you build or debug

Comment: Thank you for replay @Mayur kerasiya,i will try that.